# How to add new row on Excel using PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Hi I'm new to this library called PHPSpreadsheet.
I tried reading it's docs but I can't understand it.

I want to insert a new row on an **existing** Excel File and
here is what I have so far:

```
<?php 

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$inputFileName = 'Excel/hello.xlsx';
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Updated');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('../controller/excel/hello.xlsx');

?>
```

This inserts new data on the 'hello.xsls' file **replacing the cell's previous data**. How can I make it **write data into a new row**?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To create a new row, you need to call [`insertNewRowBefore()`](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/master/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.html#method_insertNewRowBefore) with the row number you want to insert before...

```
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->insertNewRowBefore(1);
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Updated');
```

You can also call it with a number of rows to insert, the default is 1.

If you want to append a row, you can call `getHighestRow()` to find the last row and add 1 to it for the new row.  Also change the hard coding of the column in the `setCellValue()` call to use this row as well...

```
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$row = $sheet->getHighestRow()+1;
$sheet->insertNewRowBefore($row);
$sheet->setCellValue('A'.$row, 'Updated');
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll Check it. Is there any way to insert new row after rather than before? and if yes, how can I get the last row number to use it as a parameter  ?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! I've learned something again. This answers my question! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think this issue came because of memory exhausted so increase your memory limit by php.ini file

like memory_limit = 256M

After increase memory limit , restart your apache

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer throws exception:
"Column references should not be numeric."

For me works:

```
...
$row = 'A' . ($sheet->getHighestRow() +1);
$sheet->insertNewColumnBefore($row);
$sheet->setCellValue($row, 'Hello World again!');
...
```

Comment: You're mixing rows and columns. To add a row use `$sheet->insertNewRowBefore($rowNumber);`, where $rowNumber is an integer, not an "A1" cell reference string.

Comment: To add a column use `$sheet->insertNewColumnBefore($columnLetter);`, where $columnLetter is something like 'C'. There's no need to add a number to the column (in fact, the method itself cats a "1" to the end of the string you provide, so when you say `insertNewColumnBefore('C1')` it actually processes as 'C11'! (but that doesn't matter - the column is still in the right place)