# How to read and write on Excel using PHPSpreadsheet at same time?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I want to read the excel file and write the data in the next cell simultaneously.

I am using the PhpSpreadsheet library [Github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet). What I had tried is

```
$inputFileType = 'Xlsx';
$inputFileName = 'phones.xlsx';
$sheetname = 'sheet1';

/**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
$inputFileType = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);

/**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);


/**  Load $inputFileName to a Spreadsheet Object  **/
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);

/**  Convert Spreadsheet Object to an Array for ease of use  **/
$schdeules = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();

foreach( $schdeules as $single_schedule )
{               
    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach( $single_schedule as $key => $single_item )
    {
        if($_REQUEST['inbound_phone_no'] == $single_item){
            // echo $key;exit;
            
// I am trying to write the data using this but nothing is going on.
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 3, 'PhpSpreadsheet');


            echo '<p class="item">Phone No Exist: ' . $single_item . '</p>';
        }else{
            echo '<p class="item">' . $single_item . '</p>';
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
}

exit;
```

I want to write some value if the request data and the value in the cell match, then update the status by writing 1 or 2 in the next empty cell of the sheet. The excel file image is

[image]

I am new to this library. So please ignore it if it's a newbie question. I had looked into the questions

[Read Xlsx file in PhpSpreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823233/read-xlsx-file-in-phpspreadsheet)
and
[How to add new row on Excel using PHPSpreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213250/how-to-add-new-row-on-excel-using-phpspreadsheet)

The help on this will highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

as the ->load loads the xlsx to memory, you change values in copy in memory.

the complete way is something like that:

```
$fileExcel          = 'load.xlsx';
$target_dir         = 'save.xlsx';
$reader             = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$spreadsheet        = $reader->load($fileExcel);
$sheet              = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$lsValue            = $sheet->getCell('A1')->getValue();
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 3, 'PhpSpreadsheet');
$writer = new  \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save($target_dir);
```

so you need the last 2 lines to save the file before your exit:

```
$writer = new  \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save($target_dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: `setCellValueByColumnAndRow` is now deprecated; use `setCellValue` instead.

This is a simple way to read and write from and to the same Xlsx files using phpoffice/phpspreadsheet version 1.29:

```php
$inputFileName = "phones.xlsx";
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
$activeSheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$data = $activeSheet->toArray("", false, false); // the entire sheet as 2D array

// access each row $i, read data from column 3 to new column 4 (zero based index)
for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++)
{
    $readData = $data[$i][3]; // read row $i, column 3 (zero based index)
    
    $activeSheet->setCellValue([5,$i+1], $readData); // write to column 5, row $i+1 (one based index)
}

$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save($inputFileName); // save to the same file
```